# Help with working out resistor value for broken circuit

Tags: resistors

[image: datasheets]

I am repairing a PCB from an oven. Found a triac to be faulty. There is a missing resistor though and I need to know its value.

Its part of the MOC3052 snubber circuit, the snubber circuit for noisy environments has a 10 µF capacitor and 47 W resistor.

The basic driver circuit has a capacitor of 10 nF and resistor of 33 Ω.

Whats confusing me is the board has a 22 nF capacitor, not the ones mentioned.

So how do I work out a suitable resistor replacement? Would 40 Ω be okay?

Comment: 47 w resistor or 47 ohm resistor? Where did you get the circuit values from an example circuit or from the manual?

Comment: It says 47 W in the diagram which I'm guessing is 47ohms. It's only included one picture here for some reason but that one says 33 W. I have gotten this from the datasheet for the MOC3052

Comment: It's definitely this circuit here: https://imgur.com/a/uRNYbIo but my capacitor is 0.22uf

Comment: Here's some more pictures of the circuit, it's R73 that's missing https://imgur.com/a/qmg3yxn

Answer (score 0):

> So how do I work out a suitable resistor replacement?

Snubbers are designed to keep the dv/dt in valid range for the triac which is usually an issue with inductive loads. The other thing that snubbers do is prevent high voltage spikes from triggering the triac.

I would suggest using the values of resistor and capacitor that were originally in the design. That doesn't work you may have to simulate the circuit and find the best values for the snubber.

Using values from the MOC data sheet may not be the best idea because they won't be tuned in for the load.

Comment: It came from the factory with the 0.22uf capacitor. I'll put a 40ohm resistor there and see how it goes I guess. Its in between both of those values shown on the datasheets

Comment: I've only got 33ohm or 47ohm 2W resistors, which do you think would be best?

Comment: Hard to say, well actually happened with the original circuit did the triac burn out?

Comment: I've gone for 33ohm as it's closer to the diagrams value for the capacitance. The variac was faulty and so was the 0.22uf capacitor, it was coming up with 129nf instead of 220nf. I have replaced both of those which leaves the resistor which I'm guessing, got so hot it melted it's solder points and fell off the board. It also had sent an arc between 2 of the traces but they remain undamaged.

Comment: A "Variac" is a variable autotransformer. I think you mean triac, or possibly a potentiometer used to adjust phase angle for the triac control.